# Trouble setting multiple MenuItem Methods when adding to Android Options Menu using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

I can't seem to figure out how to get my code to set multiple Methods when using Kotlin to programatically add Menu options in Android.

This code works to add a single Method (isCheckable):

```
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
       menu.clear()
       for (i in 0..shiptoList.size - 1) {
          menu.add(0, i, Menu.NONE, shiptoList[i].shipTo)
              .isCheckable = true
       }
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

But I want to add .isChecked as well.  If I add another menu.add statement (setting .isChecked), then I get duplicate Menu Options.

```
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
       menu.clear()
       for (i in 0..shiptoList.size - 1) {
          menu.add(0, i, Menu.NONE, shiptoList[i].shipTo)
              .isCheckable = true
          menu.add(0, i, Menu.NONE, shiptoList[i].shipTo)
              .isChecked = true
       }
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

I can't figure how to create a MenuItem object so that I can set both Methods then add the MenuItem to the menu.  I also don't see a way to change an existing MenuItem or I could use this for my second Method.

I certainly appreciate some guidance on this!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran into the answer on another post:

```
   override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menu.clear()
        for (i in 0..shiptoList.size - 1) {
            menu.add(
                0,
                i,
                Menu.NONE,
                "${shiptoList[i].shipToName}:${shiptoList[i].shipToCode}"
            ).apply {
                isCheckable = true
                isChecked = if (shiptoList[i].selected) true else false
            }
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```